# How to make print statement one line in python?

Tags: python

How do i make this code print as one line?:

```
 print("If a hippo ways 2000 pounds, gives birth to a 100 pound calf and
          then eats a 50 pound meal how much does she weigh?")
```

I have it this way to make it more readable, i know i could use triple quotes to get it to print exactly the way it is and that i could use a comma to separate the statement into two lines, but that would make two separate strings(I think). is there a way to keep the statement as one string and have it print out as one line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adjacent string literals are concatenated implicitly:

```
print("If a hippo ways 2000 pounds, gives birth to a 100 pound calf and "
       "then eats a 50 pound meal how much does she weigh?")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("If a hippo ways 2000 pounds, gives birth to a 100 pound calf and "\
      +"then eats a 50 pound meal how much does she weigh?")
```

Comment: Inside parentheses/braces/brackets, there is no need for explicit line continuation. In fact, some (including the PEP 8 authors) find this always preferable to ``\``.

Comment: The solution with a backslash is working but it is ugly.

Comment: OK didn't know the adjacent string auto-concatenation,thanks!